# How can I always pass the current variable value into a python function?

Tags: python, excel, function, variables, openpyxl

I have a project where I want the user to specify input parameters in an excel sheet that is then read into multiple functions within a class with openpyxl. My problem is that, whenever I change a value in the sheet I have to run the script again to make the changes effective. As I want to use the script interactively and quickly show different values, this takes to much time.

Is there another way to always pass the changed variable from the sheet into the functions?

Here is my code:

```
class input:
    def __init__(self, vals=None):
        self.vals = vals
        self.wb = load_workbook("input.xlsx", data_only = True)
        self.ws = self.wb.get_active_sheet()

    def get_var(self):
        self.var = self.ws["B3"].value
        return self.var
        wb.save()
input.input()
```

Before getting values from an excel sheet, I had the parameters in another module which was imported into the main module. I had the same problem there but figured that was caused by the import command. I the looked into reloading module but does not seem to solve the problem. Then I introduced the functions which I thought would do it but no success.

Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The easiest way to do this, is having a scheduled job that will reload the values every X seconds/minutes

Comment: Perhaps you could use VBA and Python rather than pure Python. The VBA can be an event handler for the `Worksheet_Change` event and can invoke the Python script whenever it detects a change (or even just a change in a specified cell).

Comment: If you rely on changing data in the Excel sheet then you will always need to reload the whole workbook to read it. You might want to look at using something like xlwings in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you return before you save anything and you aren't using the save command correctly. Below I provided some sample code that will accept an input, modify a specific cell, and then save the file. There is no need for a reload. I also modified some of the variable/function names as `input` is a built-in function and shouldn't be used for class names. This is just to show you how to get the save working properly as I don't know what you actually want the code to do.

```
import openpyxl as op

class excel:
    def __init__(self, vals=None):
        self.vals = vals
        self.wb = op.load_workbook("sample.xlsx", data_only=True)
        self.ws = self.wb.active

    def set_var(self, num):
        self.ws["A1"].value = num
        self.wb.save('sample.xlsx')
        print(self.ws["A1"].value)

excel_file = excel()
while True:
    a = input()
    excel_file.set_var(a)
```